# "How to get search box to autocomplete using google maps API"

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, api-design, search-box

I am trying to get my search bar to autocomplete information from the google maps API when something is typed into the search box

```html
    <input id="searchBox" type="text" class="mainSearch" placeholder="What are you looking for?">

    <script>
    function activatePlacesSearch(){
    var input = document.getElementById('searchBox');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDebmgXVzGaZsrccgKseQvx9cuAK-6--kI&libraries=places&callback=activatePlacesSearch">
</script>
```

I created this just as one of the videos had it on youtube but nothing is populating.